# Ionic - JavaScript : Accessing properties inside a function

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

it might  be a silly question but i am a beginner so please help me on this

i want to access a **public property** and change  its value inside **setTimeout** function, Below is my code .

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public selectedIndex = 0;
  public appPages = [
    
    {
      title: 'Trash',
      url: '/folder/Trash',
      icon: 'trash'
    },
    {
      title: 'Spam',
      url: '/folder/Spam',
      icon: 'warning'
    }
  ];
  public showSplash = true;
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,

) {
    this.initializeApp();

  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      setTimeout(function() {
        //showSplash = false ;
        console.log('set timeout worked');
       }, 300);


    });
  }
```

console.log works inside **setTimeout** i need to change **showSplash** value in that block, Please help how can i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is angular and typescript code. You can use arrow function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

```
initializeApp() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.statusBar.styleDefault();
    this.splashScreen.hide();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.showSplash = false;
      console.log('set timeout worked');
    }, 300);
  });
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly, could you please explain why did it not work   i mean for referencing "this" inside a function   in angular - TS  we need to use arrow functions ? please confirm

Comment: In summary, when using `this` in the `function` syntax, it references the object `Window`. When the arrow function is used, if you examine the javascript output, it creates a definition like `var _this = this;` in the code and actually uses this variable `_this` instead of `this` in the `setTimeout` function.@SikanderNawaz